# ASP.NET Tab Controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm currently attempting to create a tabbed interface in a web application, and based on my search, there aren't any 'built in' tab controls in ASP.NET.  There are some in the [ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) downloadable toolkit, as well as a wealth of 'pay for use' third party Tab Controls.

My question is:  What Tab control have you used for ASP.NET applications, and why do you use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use MultiView/Views and your own navigation to get tabs in ASP.NET.

Comment: This is essentially the right answer. You can place the navigation just above the multiview, and based on the click, switch views. Of course, it's server side, but I think you can put it in an UpdatePanel and get it to be AJAX-y.

Comment: Yes -- I've used it in an UpdatePanel -- works great.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the AJAX [TabControl](http://www.asp.net/Ajax/Ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/Tabs/Tabs.aspx) in the past and I like it.  It's pretty straight forward.  It's easy enough to get to the active tab and its content.

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Rad [TabStrip](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/controls/tabstrip/overview.aspx) control by Telerik and it is one of the best to work with in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

We use multiviews most of the time, or, in some cases, we build our own tab controls out of a combination of link buttons and overlapping panels and swap their visibilities based on what link button has been pressed (this may seem primative, but it works well).